# ReactJS call API and Redirect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I am facing an issue in ReactJs Redux I'm trying to call API with Token from Url. If API request failed it will update the state of the recoverPasswordToken to false. I want to redirect to homepage in a failed condition. In the current case, it's don't wait for the API response and if condition running on the behalf of recoverPasswordToken default null value.

```
useEffect(() => {
        checkRecoverPasswordToken(match.params.token);
 if (!recoverPasswordToken) {
        console.log('working');
        return <Redirect to="/" />
    }
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use history api instead Redirect component

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router"
//...

const history = useHistory()

useEffect(() => {
  checkRecoverPasswordToken(match.params.token).then(()=>{
     if (recoverPasswordToken) {
        history.push("/")
      }
   });
}, []);
```

Comment: Sure. Thanks. The redirection is working fine. My question is related to recoverPasswordToken value change on API call.

Comment: If I right understand you and if checkRecoverPasswordToken is a promise you can use history api also

Comment: Thank you very much